# Why is Randy limping?

Tags: scream

During the party at Stu's house at the end of [Scream (1996)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117571/?ref_=nv_sr_2), Randy ends up alone watching the movie by himself. Eventually he wanders outside and appears at the driver-side window of the news van when Gale is trying to use the cell phone (right before she finds Kenny dead).

Randy asks where everyone went which startled Gale and she hit Randy in the face with the phone and we don't see him again for a few scenes. When we do see him, he is running toward Sidney while she is trying to get back into the house. At this point, he is limping as if something is wrong with his leg.

Why is he limping? He was fine until he got hit in the face and then next time we see him he is limping.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call this a movie mistake, as it wouldn't make sense for him to suddenly *start* limping out of nowhere.

If you remember, when he gets hit in the face, he gets thrown to the ground by Gale driving off. My only explanation is that he twisted his ankle falling. I don't think you'll get a better/more conclusive answer than that, unfortunately.

Comment: I was hoping for a deleted scene

Comment: Unfortunately, a quick google search appears to suggest there are no deleted scenes that would explain this. Boo.

Comment: I watched director’s commentary for both the scene where Gale punches Randy then drives off and the scene where Randy limps toward Sydney. No mention of why he was limping. They did say that Jamie Kennedy (Randy) put an egg-sized rock in his shoe to get the limp right. It hurt his foot so bad they almost sent him to the hospital.

Answer (score 3):

In the previous scene Randy was hit by Gale's van after Gale frenzically drove away.

It isn't shown explicitly, but you can see Randy on the ground at around 2:11 in the clip below:

I also found a reference in the [script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Scream.html)

> Randy is thrown forward, away from the van.